# Functions in haskell that contain 2 function calls

Tags: function, haskell, functional-programming

If I have a function that needs to call 2 functions, how can that be done in Haskell??

For example if I need 2 functions to print the first 10 and last 10 items in a list, and i want to call both these functions from within one function

Answer (score 2):

i assume you have two functions of type

```
f :: a -> IO ()
```

e.g.

```
printFirst :: Show a => [a] -> IO ()
printLast :: Show a => [a] -> IO ()
```

then (because IO is a monad), you can do

```
printBoth xs = printFirst xs >> printLast xs
```

or with syntactic sugar

```
printBoth xs = do
    printFirst xs
    printLast xs
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to combine the two function calls into a combined string (or list of items) and return them or output them in that same function. For instance, to print out the results of two functions:

```
print ("First function: " ++ (show (f 1)) ++ " second function: " ++ (show (f 2)))
```